Apocalyptic style, 2nd coming Christ innuendo, sacrilege
This movie I can't think of I saw in 2005, horror/thriller/drama. It probably was made between 2000 and 2005. It features 3 scary guys, costumed similarly to Hun warriors or Highlander characters. These men navigate a present day landscape approaching people and warning them that "He is coming". I feel like I recall this movie title starting with a "The". Like The Messaging (made up as example, but probably a real film)

Possibly the thriller The Visitation from 2006 with Kelly Lynch and Edward Furlong. From Wiki:

In present-day Antioch, former minister Travis Jordan still lives, after losing his faith in God three years before when his beloved wife was murdered and the criminals never found. Suddenly, miracles happen in the little town... In all the events, either a group of three men wearing black were seen nearby, or only their tall, blond (possible) leader, who seems to want everyone to know, "he is coming".

Here's the trailer:



